# Linking jar to war

Tags: java, web-applications, netbeans, jar, war

I created a project(in netbeans) where all my gui part(used swings) is in java application-1.The data from java application-1 is passed to servlets in WebApplication-1 where the details are stored to the database.The project is working fine.

I was asked to create jar/war for my project..so that it can used any where...
I have gone through creation of jar and war(also tested with sample applications).My question is how can I link java application-1(jar) to WebApplication-1(war)??

For suppose jar is imported in another system it has to use war(since servlets are there in Webapplication).How can I do this??Is there a way to bind all the project into one library??

Comment: This doesn't seem to make any sense... your GUI app uses the web service, so the only connection should be the URL. Technically, you might be able to create one archive that contains both, but it still has to be deployed twice: once on the server as a war, once on the client. You might be interested in java web start, though. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview-137531.html

Comment: Yes the only connection is HTTP url connection..

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a war directly from the outside since according to the Java EE spec wars have to be isolated. Thus any communication between the GUI app and the web app must use other channels, the most obvious being http-based communication, like webservices.

Another option might be to create an ear and put the database code (moving it out of the war) as well as the GUI app and the war into that.